# Prepopulate form on another page using query string

Tags: javascript, string, forms, populate

Is it possible to prepopulate a form on another site using query stings? Or maybe there is another way? Would be grateful for help.

Comment: Not unless you have access to the other site, on which you'd capture the query string and parse it.

Comment: I have somewhere seen that it is possible to do via CURL. Is it indeed? Could somebody please provide some sort of a tutorial?